# Terraform - AKS POD should be able to add and delete external DNS records

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dns, terraform

I want AKS POD to add and delete DNS records whenever a Service is created. I have achieved the same via GUI, But I want to use terraform to do the same.

Created AKS Cluster:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  name                = "${azurerm_resource_group.my-res-grp-in-tf.name}-cluster"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.my-res-grp-in-tf.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.my-res-grp-in-tf.name
  dns_prefix          = "${azurerm_resource_group.my-res-grp-in-tf.name}-cluster"
  kubernetes_version  = data.azurerm_kubernetes_service_versions.current.latest_version
  node_resource_group = "${azurerm_resource_group.my-res-grp-in-tf.name}-nrg"

  default_node_pool {
    name                 = "systempool"
    vm_size              = "standard_d2s_v3" 
    orchestrator_version = data.azurerm_kubernetes_service_versions.current.latest_version
    availability_zones   = [1, 2, 3]
    enable_auto_scaling  = true
    max_count            = 1
    min_count            = 1
    os_disk_size_gb      = 30
    type                 = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    node_labels = {
      "nodepool-type"    = "system"
      "environment"      = var.env
      "nodepoolos"       = "linux"
      "app"              = "system-apps" 
    } 
   tags = {
      "nodepool-type"    = "system"
      "environment"      = var.env
      "nodepoolos"       = "linux"
      "app"              = "system-apps" 
   } 
  }

# Identity (one of either identity or service_principal blocks must be specified.)
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

# Add On Profiles
  addon_profile {
        azure_policy {
            enabled =  true
    }
    kube_dashboard {
            enabled = false
        }
        http_application_routing {
            enabled = false
        }
        oms_agent {
            enabled =  true
            log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.insights.id
        }

  }

# RBAC and Azure AD Integration Block
  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true
    azure_active_directory {
      managed = true
      admin_group_object_ids = [azuread_group.aks_administrators.id]
    }
  }

# Windows Profile
  windows_profile {
    admin_username = var.windows_admin_username
    admin_password = var.windows_admin_password
  }

# Linux Profile
  linux_profile {
    admin_username = "ubuntu"
    ssh_key {
      key_data = file(var.ssh_public_key)
    }
  }

# Network Profile
  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
    load_balancer_sku = "Standard"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = var.env
  }


# login into cluster 
provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "az aks get-credentials --name ${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.name} --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.my-res-grp-in-tf.name} --admin"
  }

}
```

I have created a resource group named "dns-zone-rg"  specifically for this task.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "dns-zone-rg-tf" {
  name     = "dns-zone-rg"
  location = var.location
}
```

Created a DNS zone in "dns-zone-rg" resource group

```
resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "public-domain-dns-zone" {
  name                = "mydomain.xyz"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.dns-zone-rg-tf.name
}
```

Created Manage Identity "mi-for-dns-zone-rg" in "dns-zone-rg" resource group

```
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "manage-identity-tf" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.dns-zone-rg-tf.name
  location            = var.location
  name = "mi-for-dns-zone-rg"
}
```

Assigned "Contributor" role to manage identity "mi-for-dns-zone-rg" and given a scope to manage resources in resource group "dns-zone-rg".

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "assign-reader-to-manage-identity" {
  scope                = azurerm_resource_group.dns-zone-rg-tf.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.manage-identity-tf.principal_id
}
```

Now I want to associate this Manage Identity "mi-for-dns-zone-rg" to the "SystemNode Pool" created by AKS. I am not able to figure out how to do that. and how to fetch node pool details created by AKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, It's not possible in Terraform.
You have to use local-exec in Terraform and Azure CLI commands to achieve the same.

```
resource "null_resource" "node-pool-name"{
  depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster,azurerm_role_assignment.assign-reader-to-manage-identity]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az vmss list -g ${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.node_resource_group} --query \"[?contains(name,'aks-systempool')].name\" --out tsv > ${path.module}/system-node-poolname.txt"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az vmss identity assign -g ${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.node_resource_group} -n `cat ${path.module}/system-node-poolname.txt` --identities ${azurerm_user_assigned_identity.manage-identity-tf.id}"
  }
}
```